# Как можно сделать прерывание?

Tags: javascript

```
var shut = 3;
var target = 0;

if ((target==0)&&(shut >= 2) ){
    if (shut == 3) {
    alert("равен 3"); 
    return 3;
    }
    alert("равен 2 или более");
}
```

почему `return` не возвращает а продолжается код и выводит `alert("равен 2 или более");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может потому, что [`return`](http://javascript.ru/return) возвращает значение **функции**, а не `if`?
Хром вообще с ошибкой упал из-за ненужного `return`.

Запретить выводить второй `alert` можно через `else`:

```js
var shut = 3;
var target = 0;

if ((target == 0) && (shut >= 2)) {
  if (shut == 3)
    alert("равен 3");
  else
    alert("равен 2 или более");
}
```

Comment: спасибо помогли